# Pronunciation of ‘few’ as [ˈfjyu̯]

Tags: pronunciation, ipa

I was surprised to see that Wiktionary states *few* be pronounced as /ˈfjuː/ or /ˈfju/. I have always pronounced it as [ˈfjyu̯]. Furthermore, I've copied the pronunciation from what I've heard and when I pronounce *few* as indicated in Wiktionary – as [ˈfjuː] – it sounds wrong and different than what I usually hear. I barely even recognize *few* as [ˈfju(ː)].

**My question:** Am I pronouncing *few* incorrectly or is [ˈfjyu̯] an accurate description of the pronunciation of *few*?

---

*Other possibly useful information:*

- I'm Dutch;
- The sound [yu̯] is natively in Dutch and generally appears in words ending in *uw*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Dutch /u/ is not necessarily the same as English /u/.**

I think you may be confusing the concepts of "[phoneme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoneme)" (which corresponds to the adjective "phonemic") and "[phone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phone_(phonetics))" (which corresponds to the adjective "phonetic").

A phonetic transcription, using square brackets, represents a specific physical sound. When comparing sounds from different languages, you want to use a phonetic (bracketed) transcription.

But, Wiktionary transcriptions are *not* phonetic. They are phonemic. (They may also have other complications, like inconsistent systems being used for different words.)

A **phonemic** transcription, using slashes, like /ˈfju/, doesn't directly represent the sounds coming out of someone's mouth. It represents the minimum amount of information a native speaker needs to know in order to pronounce a word correctly; the important sound contrasts in that specific language. As a non-native speaker, you can't rely on a phonemic transcription to tell you pronunciation details.

Unlike French or Dutch, the English sound system does not distinguish between the phonetic sounds [u], [y] and [yu̯]. Some speakers may very well have a phonetic [yu̯] or something similar in "few", but it is still considered by English speakers to be the same sound as in "fool" where a phonetic [u] would be more common.

The realization of the English phoneme /u/ as the phone [y] or [yu̯] is considered a type of **fronting**, moving a vowel sound to be pronounced further forward in the mouth.

This fronting of /u/ common in North American varieties of English, especially when /u/ comes after the palatal glide /j/ or one of the coronal consonants /n, t, d, tʃ, dʒ, s, z, ʃ, ʒ/. (I think l might also be included in this list, but I'm not sure.) You can find an illustration of where this type of fronting is common at the [Atlas of North American English](http://www.atlas.mouton-content.com/secure/generalmodules/anae/unit0034/genunstart.html). The fronting is least common when /u/ is preceded by a non-coronal consonant and followed directly by /l/.

The linguist Geoff Lindsey has made some blog posts mentioning the existence of this front realization of /uː/ in "[Standard Southern British](http://englishspeechservices.com/blog/british-vowels/)", and the tendency to use a more back realization [before "dark l"](http://englishspeechservices.com/blog/goose-backing/).

Comment: Ah, I think this was indeed the case, so this makes perfect sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

The [y] sound (high-front-tense-rounded vowel) doesn't usually appear in modern English.  Native English speakers will usually hear [y] as if it were [u] (high-back-rounded) or [ij] (high-front-unrounded with palatal glide) , so your personal pronunciation, while slightly different from that of a native speaker, will be easily understood.

Comment: That's helpful to know! But considering both `[yu̯]`and `[u(ː)]` appear in my native language, I should easily be able to distinguish the two, yet I clearly her `[yu̯]` instead of `[u(ː)]` in the pronunciation of _few_ of English speakers (and even in the audio sample from Wiktionary), which still seems very strange.

Comment: The palatal glide [j] will muddy the waters somewhat.  Because it's so close to [i] and [y], it's very hard to distinguish.  I wonder, how do you pronounce "blue"?  I would be surprised if you heard it as [blyu].

Comment: I hear _blue_ as `[bluː]` and I think it does not quite rhyme with _few_.

Comment: Exactly.  Because [y] isn't phonemic in English, we have no qualms with going through that spot in the vowel space on our way from [j] to [u].

Comment: Ah, I think I get it. So, if I'm understanding you correctly, when pronouncing _few_, the sound `[y]` tends to be in there briefly when going from `[j]` to `[u]`, which makes it sound very similar to `[ˈfjyu̯]`. Does that make sense? Does that also mean that if I very strictly pronounce _few_ like `[ˈfjuː]`, it may sound slightly odd to some native speakers, because I am not passing through `[y]` whilst they would?

Comment: @Joffysloffy: Have you been talking to Americans? it sounds American to me. There are definitely American dialects that put a [y] somewhere in words with ew (and, I believe, also ones that don't).

Comment: @PeterShor Yes! The English I come into contact with is generally almost exclusively American (like the tv shows I watch, etc., except for the occasional British detective haha).